# Are there any SMTP servers that support the SMTPUTF8 extension?

Tags: email, smtp, email-server, utf-8

RFC 5321 limits email addresses to 7 bit US-ASCII encoding.  RFC 6531 (a fairly new spec) allows email addresses in SMTP commands and IMF headers to be encoded in UTF-8.  This SMTP extension makes internationalized email addresses (e.g., pelé@example.com) possible.

An SMTP server advertises support for internationalized email by replying to the `EHLO` command with the `SMTPUTF8` keyword:

```
250-smtp.example.com at your service
250 SMTPUTF8
```

An SMTP client utilizes this extension with the `MAIL` command:

```
MAIL FROM:<pelé@example.com> SMTPUTF8
```

Question:  Are there any SMTP servers or email clients that support SMTPUTF8?

Comment: Not according to [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_SMTP#List_of_supporting_clients).

Comment: I've read that, thanks, but WP is not always current.  :-(

Comment: The hold is not appropriate.  Read the question.  It's not a request for a recommendation.  It's asking for the state of the art.

Comment: LOL.  Earned a silver badge for a Notable Question, yet it was closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postfix supports a subset of SMTPUTF8 since version 2.12: http://www.postfix.org/SMTPUTF8_README.html

Answer (score 1):

Edit:  This answer is no longer true.

As far as I can tell, at this time (Feb 2013) there are no SMTP servers or email clients that support `SMTPUTF8`.